# Checking if data reader returns rows

Tags: vb.net

What function(s) should i use to check if my datareader returns a row when running through the columns of an SQL compact 3.5 database? Apparently using dr.hasrows throws that error that says SQL compact edition does not support .hasrows if the records are non-scrollable. And using the resultsetoption.scrollable when using datareader.executeresultset gives me a "no data exists for the row/column" error when the record i am trying to pull out clearly has a record in my database. And using the if typeof datareader("ColumnName") is dbnull does nothing, like in this example:

```
  While dr.Read
        If Not TypeOf dr("LibrarianID") Is DBNull Then
            If dr("LibrarianID") = txtUserID.Text And dr("LibrarianPassword") = txtPassword.Text Then
                MsgBox("Successfully logged in.", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Logged in to library")
                Me.Hide()
                main.tslUserLoggedIn.Text = dr("FirstName") & "  " & dr("MI") & "  " & dr("LastName")
                main.tslPosition.Text = "Librarian"
                main.Show()
            Else
                MsgBox("Username and password mismatch!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Login error")
            End If

        Else
            MsgBox("User not found!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Login error")
        End If
    End While
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If expecting one record, try:

```
If dr.Read Then
  If dr("LibrarianID") IsNot Nothing Then
    // something...
  End If
Else
  // no records
End If
```